# Is it possible to make container draggable? jsplumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I would like to know if its possible to make a jsPlumb container draggable.
If you click and drag on the container(not on an element) it moves as a unit being able to focus on different parts or elements of this container.
E.g. a flow-chart like the example in their web page; 
http://www.jsplumb.org/demo/flowchart/jquery.html 
and i want the whole container to move if i click and drag so that all elements inside move as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0q9dds7n/). First push the New container button, then the New cell inside container. You can drag the container as well as the cells inside it.

JavaScript:

```
var instanceRegistry = [];
var containerRegistry = [];
var cellRegistry = [];

$(function() {

var endpointOptions = {
   isSource: true,
    isTarget: true
};

$('#newContainerButton').click(newContainer);
$('#newCellButton').click(newCell);

function newContainer() {
var containerIndex = "container" + (containerRegistry.length + 1);
$('#containerTemplate').clone().appendTo('#mainContainer')
    .show()
    .attr('id', containerIndex)
    .draggable({
    containment: 'mainContainer',
    cursor: 'move'
    })
    .find('.newCellButton').click(newCell).end();

containerRegistry.push(containerIndex);
var containerInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    Container: containerIndex,
    Endpoint: [                     // The default Endpoint definition.
        'Dot',                      // Endpoint type
        {                           // Endpoint type options
            radius: 6,              // Defines the radius of the dot
            cssClass: 'cell-endpoint' // A CSS class to attach to the element the Endpoint creates
            }
    ],
    PaintStyle: {                   // The default appearance of a Connector
        strokeStyle: '#2e6f9a',     // color for a Connector
        lineWidth: 2                // width of a Connector's line
    }
});
instanceRegistry.push(containerInstance);
}




function newCell(event) {
var $container = $(event.target).parent();
var cellIndex = "cell" + (cellRegistry.length + 1);
$('#cellTemplate').clone().appendTo($container)
    .show()
    .attr('id', cellIndex);
cellRegistry.push(cellIndex);

var num = containerRegistry.indexOf($container.attr('id'));
var instance = instanceRegistry[num];

instance.draggable(cellIndex, {
    containment: $container,
    cursor: 'move'
});

instance.addEndpoint(cellIndex, {anchor: "Top"}, endpointOptions);
instance.addEndpoint(cellIndex, {anchor: "Right"}, endpointOptions);
instance.addEndpoint(cellIndex, {anchor: "Bottom"}, endpointOptions);
instance.addEndpoint(cellIndex, {anchor: "Left"}, endpointOptions);
}

});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, i'll try to explain a bit better what i want. I dont want the whole container to be draggable i'm looking for a way if possible to make that container stay fixed and move around everything thats inside it and the items inside shouldnt lose their "patterns" of behaviour. Something like a GPS, the container is always the same and the "buildings" and all info stays the same yet you can move around and watch different sections... I dont know if i made it a bit more clear sorry... thanks in advance!

Comment: For people trying the example, don't forget to update the external dependency to jsplumb, because the one in it is outdated and not found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this eazily with the jQuery Library named - "jQuery UI".

Check the following link:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

You will be able to do it eazily, in 5 minutes.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, i'll try to explain a bit better what i want. I dont want the whole container to be draggable i'm looking for a way if possible to make that container stay fixed and move around everything thats inside it and the items inside shouldnt lose their "patterns" of behaviour. Something like a GPS, the container is always the same and the "buildings" and all info stays the same yet you can move around and watch different sections... I dont know if i made it a bit more clear sorry... thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to have ajax calls for that. Google map uses ajax to load data from server. It will be a complex scenario but you may do this like this: 
1) Make fixed container - Div 1 {width:100px;height:100px;}
2) Make Div2 inside div1 {width:1000px;height:1000px;} and make this draggable. 
3) Now, you get the effect of contents moving inside a fixed container

Comment: Ok, i got the basic idea thanks i'll play with that a bit around!

Comment: Welcome, dear! Hope, you get it.